# primitive types enum - does it exist

Tags: c#, enums, primitive-types

I need to provide a user a list of all primitive types available and was wondering if there is an Enum in the .net library that has all primitive types, so that I don't have to build one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The nearest you are going to get is [System.TypeCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.typecode.aspx).

Comment: This will suffice. Thanks bunch

Answer (score 14):

Not an enum, but:

```
var primitives = typeof(int).Assembly.GetTypes()
       .Where(type => type.IsPrimitive).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no such enum.