# What is the difference between the terms non-primitive type and object type?

Tags: java, c#, object, types, primitive

When I read about Java, I generally see variables described as either **primitive type** or **object type**.

When I read about C#, I generally see variables described as either **primitive type** or **non-primitive type**?

What is the difference between the terms **object type** and **non-primitive type**?

Comment: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1491/datatypes-in-csharp

Comment: That article mis-identifies most of the primitive types, from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive(v=vs.110).aspx) - "The primitive types are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, IntPtr, UIntPtr, Char, Double, and Single."

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589111/primitive-types-versus-built-in-value-types

Comment: In Java, variables can only be primitives or references. You can't have variables which are objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of this confusion may be in that, in C#, [(mostly) everything inherits from Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436211/is-everything-in-net-an-object). To refer to an Object type in the same way, would refer to every type in the language, and essentially be useless.

In C#, the primitive types are Boolean, Byte, Char, Double, Int16, Int32, Int64, IntPtr, SByte, Single, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UIntPtr. These types still inherit from object, though they are treated differently by the language. There are a few types that *don't* inherit from object, but they are not what you would consider primitives (ie Interfaces). The list of C# primitives can be acquired with this code, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826664/primitive-types-enum-does-it-exist):

```
var primitives = typeof(int).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsPrimitive).ToArray();
```

A more appropriate dichotomy, if you wanted such a thing, would be value types versus reference types. When you begin considering that difference, then you can include things such as Enum types, and other values type, like structs.

Comment: one should also have in mind boxing/unboxing btw

Answer (score 0):

in Java:

the **primitive variables** are categorized in 8 data types: boolean,byte,short,int,long,float,double and char.Every primitive variable has his own range of space in memory.

The **references variables**,refers to objects(Array,String,ArrayList,StringBuilder,...), and doesnt matter the space of the object referred.

**Differences:**

1.references types can be assinged as null /primitives dont.

2.references types can be used to call methods when they dont point to   null/primitives uses literals.

3.references types have all the same size / in primitives depends of the
   data type

4.primitives declarations starts with lowercase/java classes with
   Uppercase